# Create animation to make object move at different speeds along a continous path in svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate, svg.js

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/vceakozz/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vceakozz) which is a SVG.js tutorial moves a square back and forth in a spiral.

```js
    var canvas = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,800,1000)
      , rect = canvas.rect(100, 100)
      , path = canvas.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113")
      , length = path.length()
      
    path.fill('none').stroke({width:1, color: '#000'})
    
    rect.animate(8000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
        var p = path.pointAt(eased * length)
        rect.center(p.x, p.y)
    }).loop(true, true)
```

```css
html, body, #drawing{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

My requirement is to make the square move slower first (move 0.65*path_length for a large animation time) and next make the square move faster in the rest of the path (move 0.35*path_length for a smaller animation time)

You can find the new fiddle below, which doesn't work as expected.

```js
var canvas = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,800,1000)
  , rect = canvas.rect(100, 100)
  , path = canvas.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113")
  , length = path.length()
 
path.fill('none').stroke({width:1, color: '#000'})

rect.animate(8000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
    length1 = 0.65*length
    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length1)
    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
}).animate(2000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
    length2 = 0.35*length
    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length2)
    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
})
```

```css
html, body, #drawing{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

The problem is that the second animate call starts the square at position 0,0 instead of the point where the square stops after the first animate call.

Using the move function as shown below, to position the square at the updated location (final location of the previous animation) also doesn't have an effect in changing the position of the square.

```js
var canvas = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,800,1000)
  , rect = canvas.rect(100, 100)
  , path = canvas.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113")
  , length = path.length()
 
path.fill('none').stroke({width:1, color: '#000'})

rect.animate(8000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
    length1 = 0.65*length
    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length1)
    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
}).after(function(){
 rect.move(rect.transform().x, rect.transform().y)
}).animate(2000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased){
 length2 = 0.35*length
    var p = path.pointAt(eased * length2)
    rect.center(p.x, p.y)
})
```

```css
html, body, #drawing{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Is it possible to have the object move in two different speeds along a continuous path?

Comment: `eased * length2` has to be `eased * length2 + length1` because you want to start where you stopped

Comment: Thanks, @Fuzzyma for pointing out where the issue was in my code. It works after your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

You need to map 'pos' values from the range 0 to 1, to the new two-part range you desire.

- Map values in the range (0 -> 0.8) to the range (0 -> 0.65)
- Map values in the range (0.8 -> 1.0) to the range (0.65 -> 1.0)

```js
var canvas = SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%').viewbox(0,0,800,1000)
  , rect = canvas.rect(100, 100)
  , path = canvas.path("m 357.64532,453.84097 c 17.62007,8.02216 -2.12058,27.70935 -13.33334,29.28571 -30.3859,4.27185 -48.34602,-29.97426 -45.23807,-55.9524 5.5594,-46.46879 56.1311,-70.59787 98.57145,-61.19043 62.28294,13.8058 93.32728,82.57702 77.1428,141.19051 C 453.21679,585.29693 365.67122,623.42358 290.97859,600.26951 196.98554,571.13248 151.71003,464.56996 181.93108,373.84089 218.53281,263.95583 344.23687,211.49702 450.97875,248.84102 576.77037,292.84963 636.43303,437.76771 591.93099,560.50775 540.55162,702.21597 376.3736,769.09583 237.6452,717.41234 80.01319,658.68628 5.9069261,475.21736 64.788247,320.50751 130.84419,146.94643 333.62587,65.607117 504.31214,131.69819 693.80625,205.0718 782.38357,427.18225 709.07382,613.84113")
  , length = path.length()
 
path.fill('none').stroke({width:1, color: '#000'})

rect.animate(10000, '<>').during(function(pos, morph, eased) {
  // Note: we are using the eased position ('eased') rather than the linear position ('pos')
  if (eased <= 0.8) {
    // Convert pos in the range (0 -> 0.8) to the range (0 -> 0.65)
    var adjustedPos = eased * 0.65 / 0.8;
  } else {
    // Convert pos in the range (0.8 -> 1.0) to the range (0.65 -> 1.0)
    var adjustedPos = 0.65 + ((eased - 0.8) * 0.35 / 0.2);
  }
  var p = path.pointAt(adjustedPos * length)
  rect.center(p.x, p.y)
});
```

```css
html, body, #drawing{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Comment: How did the mapping for 0 - 0.65 and 0.65 - 1 be 0 - 0.8 and 0.8 - 1 respectively? Is there a specific way you got 0.8?

Comment: Is it related to the proportion of the animation time?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have explained that.  You had a 10 second animation time. 0.8 of which was in the first animation.

Comment: You have to use the linear pos when you want to check against time. Eased pos after 0.8 is not 8 seconds. That's only true for the linear position

Comment: Yes. Good point.  But it does allow you to get easing behaviour simply.

Comment: Thanks, PaulLeBeau, and @Fuzzyma. Since I need the position w.r.t. the time I had to go with using the linear pos. But I agree with using the eased pos to get a more visually appealing animation.